# jump to a certain place in html/css

Tags: html, css, button

I have **two question**:

1) How can I let the start button work. My idea is that if you click on start that it jumps to the text i wrote.

2) The hover function in my header **doesn't work**. It used to work but now it doesn't so I am kind of confused.

Can anyone help me fine the problem i'm missing something.

Thanks

```css
body {
    /*geld voor alles */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.centered {
    /* maak tekst in het midden*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header {
    /*balk boven aan gemaakt met w3schools en hulp van forums */
    background-color: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.content {
    /* geen idee stond op w3schools */
    padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
    /* voor de header*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
    /* voor de header */
    padding-top: 102px;
}

.logo {
    /* logo linksboven */
    Width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
    float: left;
}

h1.startdereis {
    /* tekst met start de reis */
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -80px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.straatfoto {
    /* de straat met een donker filter */
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(straat.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.knop {
    /* start knop */
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 550px;
}

.knop1 {
    /* start knop*/
    border: 3px solid white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: darkorange;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    margin-left: -300px;
}

.hoofd-nav {
    /* voor de header */
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.hoofd-nav li {
    /* voor de header */
    display: inline-block;
}

.hoofd-nav li a {
    /* voor de header */
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.hoofd-nav li a.actief {
    /* maakt een vierkantje om de actieve onderwerp */
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.hoofd-nav li a:hover {
    ?
    /* maakt een blokje als je er overheen gaat */
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.voorstellen
{
    max-width: 600px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: Black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Duco's Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<header>
    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
        <img class="logo" src="leeuw.png">
        <ul class="hoofd-nav">
            <li><a href="" class="actief"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Voorstellen </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Hobby's </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Toekomstdromen </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function() {
            myFunction()
        };

        var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
        var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                header.classList.add("sticky");
            } else {
                header.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }

    </script>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="straatfoto"></div>
        <div class="centered">
            <h1 class="startdereis">Start De Reis</h1>
            <div class="knop">
                <a href="" class="knop1"> Start </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="voorstellen">
        <h2>Wie ben ik?</h2>
        <p>Mijn volledige naam is Duco Gerard van de Schepop. Mijn tweede naam komt van mijn hele muzikale opa, die ik helaas nooit gekent heb. Op het moment dat ik werd geboren had ik geen opa's meer en nog maar een oma. Mijn enige oma die nog leefde woonde in Duitsland. We zochten haar meestal om de vakantie op. Voor mij was het meestal best saai want ik sprak toen ik klein was sprak ik nog geen Duits, dus was het moeilijk om met mijn oma te praten en in een bejaardenhuis is nou eenmaal weinig te doen. Op het moment dat ik in de tweede wat Duits had geleerd en ook echt zelf wat kon zeggen tegen mijn oma i.p.v dat mijn ouder het zouden vertalen stierf mijn oma jammer genoeg.
            <br><br>
            Nu even genoeg over mijn opa's en oma's. Ik woon vijtien jaar in Soest met mijn vader, moeder en sinds dat ik drie werd ook een kleiner zusje. Er is niet echt iets bijzonders dat ik kan vertellen over mijn gezin, we zijn gewoon een doodgewoon gezin.
            <br><br>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding an ID to your text div and changing the link of your start button to #yourid.

Here's a working demo:

```css
body {
    /*geld voor alles */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.centered {
    /* maak tekst in het midden*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header {
    /*balk boven aan gemaakt met w3schools en hulp van forums */
    background-color: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.content {
    /* geen idee stond op w3schools */
    padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
    /* voor de header*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
    /* voor de header */
    padding-top: 102px;
}

.logo {
    /* logo linksboven */
    Width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
    float: left;
}

h1.startdereis {
    /* tekst met start de reis */
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -80px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.straatfoto {
    /* de straat met een donker filter */
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(straat.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.knop {
    /* start knop */
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 550px;
}

.knop1 {
    /* start knop*/
    border: 3px solid white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: darkorange;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    margin-left: -300px;
}

.hoofd-nav {
    /* voor de header */
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.hoofd-nav li {
    /* voor de header */
    display: inline-block;
}

.hoofd-nav li a {
    /* voor de header */
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.hoofd-nav li a.actief {
    /* maakt een vierkantje om de actieve onderwerp */
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.hoofd-nav li a:hover {
    ?
    /* maakt een blokje als je er overheen gaat */
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.voorstellen
{
    max-width: 600px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: Black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Duco's Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<header>
    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
        <img class="logo" src="leeuw.png">
        <ul class="hoofd-nav">
            <li><a href="" class="actief"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Voorstellen </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Hobby's </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Toekomstdromen </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function() {
            myFunction()
        };

        var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
        var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                header.classList.add("sticky");
            } else {
                header.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }

    </script>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="straatfoto"></div>
        <div class="centered">
            <h1 class="startdereis">Start De Reis</h1>
            <div class="knop">
                <a href="#textjump" class="knop1"> Start </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="voorstellen" id="textjump">
        <h2>Wie ben ik?</h2>
        <p>Mijn volledige naam is Duco Gerard van de Schepop. Mijn tweede naam komt van mijn hele muzikale opa, die ik helaas nooit gekent heb. Op het moment dat ik werd geboren had ik geen opa's meer en nog maar een oma. Mijn enige oma die nog leefde woonde in Duitsland. We zochten haar meestal om de vakantie op. Voor mij was het meestal best saai want ik sprak toen ik klein was sprak ik nog geen Duits, dus was het moeilijk om met mijn oma te praten en in een bejaardenhuis is nou eenmaal weinig te doen. Op het moment dat ik in de tweede wat Duits had geleerd en ook echt zelf wat kon zeggen tegen mijn oma i.p.v dat mijn ouder het zouden vertalen stierf mijn oma jammer genoeg.
            <br><br>
            Nu even genoeg over mijn opa's en oma's. Ik woon vijtien jaar in Soest met mijn vader, moeder en sinds dat ik drie werd ook een kleiner zusje. Er is niet echt iets bijzonders dat ik kan vertellen over mijn gezin, we zijn gewoon een doodgewoon gezin.
            <br><br>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```